# password doesn't confirm in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

rule in model password confirm not work how to fix it

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'email'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['username', 'email', 'status','password','confirmpassword'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        // password field is required on 'create' scenario

   ['confirmpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'message'=>"Passwords don't match"],

        // use passwordStrengthRule() method to determine password strength
        $this->passwordStrengthRule(),

        ['username', 'unique', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom validation and not use a code validation inside rules return array  ( i think the  code you use inside array break the validation..)

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'email'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['username', 'email', 'status','password','confirmpassword'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        // use a custom validation functio call 
        ['password', 'passwordStrengthRule']


        ['confirmpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'message'=>"Passwords don't match"],



        ['username', 'unique', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
    ];
}

// function  for custom validation of password strenght
public function passwordStrengthRule($attribute, $params)
{

  //your password Strength Validation rule code 
  //eg: 
   return $this->passwordStrengthRule($attribute);

}
```

[see this doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) for a brief input validation's guide